# filter value from json object

Tags: javascript, json, filter, immutable.js

## i have json object idAndNames.json;

```
[

  { "id":"1", "name":"name1"},

  { "id":"2", "name":"name2"},

  { "id":"3", "name":"name3"}

]
```

## i want to filter it by id and name

```
function checkFilter(id,valueItem) {

return id <= valueItem;

}
//i changed json to array with immutable.js -> fromJS(idAndNames);

idAndNamesArray.filter(item => checkFilter(item.get('id'),valueItem));
```

but i cant filter it by id or name

when valueItem=1; integer i get error: "Expected Array or iterable object of values"

when valueItem="1" string it doesnt give any error it just doesnt work

can you help me to find the correct way? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle with your code and it works with int or string: https://jsfiddle.net/nyvbb4nd/1/

Did you declare `valueItem` in your code?

```
var valueItem='1'; //1
var result = idAndNamesArray.filter(item => checkFilter(item.get('id'),valueItem));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you are right code is working. I just found I was missing something else thank you for your responses

Comment: is there a way to use checkFilter func for both id and name item => checkFilter(item.get('id'),valueItem)  is just for id what if i want to use same function for all values of array?

Answer (score 0):

If you've only used Immutable for this task, I'd avoid it and just use ES6 syntax:

I've updated `checkFilter` to return a function so that it can work on each filtered element. All you need to do is pass in `valueItem`

```
const checkFilter = (valueItem) => (el) => el.id <= valueItem;
let result = data.filter(checkFilter('2'));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/noykt7w7/1/)